# Uncontrollable and uncorrelatable blue screens

Tags: bsod

I keep having my laptop bluescreen at random time that I can’t seem to correlate when it's happening.

At first I thought it was a hardware problem as it almost seemed to correlate with when I picked up my laptop, but it is definitely not just then, but it still almost seems to partially correlate with that. I am not sure.

Tried the drivers that I could think of and am starting to wonder if it is a RAM error (hoping not because I believe it is soldered to the mobo).

My laptop is a [Samsung NP940X3G-s03US](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/NP940X3G-S03US). 8GB of RAM, dual core i5.  I have tried everything I could think of and everything I could find online.

A copy of the [event logs and minidumps are located here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7Q8-e9b3TPiOWZBaXRKVWwtbms&usp=drive_web).

Let me know if you need anything else of it I did anything wrong, let me know.

Comment: First: what does the BSoD state the issue is?? Research the hex error ID. Second:The easiest way to differentiate software vs. hardware issue: make a bootable USB flash stick, e.g. Windows PE (very limited ability) or Ubuntu Linux. If the laptop functions flawlessly then the issue is with the internal HDD or a software error.

Comment: DrMoishe Pippik, I sadly did not write down what the errors were(it is different different times).  It's not really an option to use a flashdrive as it runs for days without problems and then blue screens 6 times in one day.  I have replaced the SSD with a different one and did a clean windows install.

Comment: you need to share the dump files from C:\Windows\minidump

Comment: Added to folder with event logs.  Please see OP.  Thanks for your helps so far.

Comment: you have so many different crashes that you should check the RAM for errors with memtest86+

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was away from my computer for a couple weeks.  I got no errors when running memtest86.  I am shocked, not gonna lie.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a hardware error - and, unfortunately, it could very well be RAM.    Download a Stress Testing Boot image and do a burn-in test - One such package is "[stresslinux](http://www.stresslinux.org/sl/)"  (I've not used this particular variant though).

Comment: I ran memtest for around 12 hours with no errors so I am slightly confused.  I tried the stresslinux but it doesn't seem to work with my laptop (maybe desktop only..? Or my display res).  Hooked up an external monitor and it still didn't work.